# Obtener FileStream de N archivos

Tags: c#

Hola a todos como puedo guardar en un arreglo el stream de los archivos almacenados en una carpeta. este es mi codigo:

```
string ruta = @"C:\";
foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(ruta))
{
 //Obtengo en (s) todos los archivos almacenado en la carpeta
 FileStream filestr= File.OpenRead(s);    
 }
```

Guardo en la variable filestr el stream del archivo s, pero este cambiara conforme recorra el foreach, existe alguna manera de guardar el stream de cada archivo, en un arreglo para posteriormente usarlo.

Comment: si la he modificado por c#   =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias crear un array de FileStream para asignar cada lectura

```
List<FileStream> list = new List<FileStream>();

string ruta = @"C:\";
foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(ruta))
{
    FileStream filestr = File.OpenRead(s);   
    list.Add(filestr);
}
```

igualmente no creo que sea recomendado mantener en memoria muchos archivo abiertos, porque recuerda que quedaran bloqueados mientras estan bajo lectura

Nota: no definas como ruta c:\ es para problemas

**>>pero como puedo cerrar el filestream**

Si tienes la lista podrias iterarla para cerrar cada archivo abierto

```
foreach(var file in list){
  file.Close();
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Alejandro, pero como puedo cerrar el filestream algo como filestr .EndRead, he leido un poco pero como incorporar la parte del  Async

Comment: si tienes la lista podrias iterarla para cerrar cada archivo abierto